Immediately stop complation if any cross links missing in Tex file
How do I tell the latex compiler to immediately stop compiling file and alert me if any cross-links are missing in the TeX file?

As cross references are resolved only in the second compilation stopping the compilation directly means that you will never get a final result.

@Ulrike Fischer - Yes. You are right. But some times team members are moved with (?) or ?? to proof reading. To avoid this I want to put some warnings in compilation time. Once they fixed missing links it will be helpful for both sides.

Per day we are working for more than 100 journals. So this request is more helpful for me.

Also we avoid unwanted Rework (some times Ref cross links are in Author Name & Year or Number format).

There are warnings in the log if references didn't resolve.

There are already warnings in the log and not only for each missing reference but also as a summary at the end of the LaTeX run. So you just need to search for LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references. at the end of the log file.

??? It should be easy to add a test like if grep '^LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.' *.log; then exit 1;fi into the build process. And IMHO this shouldn't be the only automatic test. BTW: LaTeX cannot test itself, if hyperlinks to external URLs are valid. But those should nevertheless be tested too.

Yes. It's in log file. But, There's a chance to missing links in proof at any of the stages (they were not checking properly in log file before creating the ps or pdf. This is the main cause). So I decided to put check point in compilation time itself. No body release proof with missing cross links. Please advise.

@cabohah - I will try this... and let you know. Thanks

If you want to check missing links without making a PDF (or PS) you would need a LaTeX source analyzer. LaTeX cannot do this, if you don't make LaTeX runs. And as Ulrike already told: In the first LaTeX-run at least the \label, \ref references are always unknown. So if you want to know the real missing references, you need at least two LaTeX runs. And after these you can always analyze the log.

Both of your  points are I agreed. My intention is "No Missing links" appear after creating the pdf output. So  without checking log file any options to control this issues? Or use of any tool or macros etc...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

well, if you use a makefile or similar, you could always have it delete the PDF if the log contains the warnings. But doing this also makes it harder for people to identify where the problems are. Yes, you can go through the log. But it is handy to be able to search for say ?? in the PDF at times. And there are numerous other reasons you might need to recompile.

@cfr - I haven't used any makefile it is just standard template. We follow simple ps to pdf conversion method.

@KGSR It was not a serious suggestion. As I say, packages and commands typically produce visual markers to help users find unresolved references etc. And even if you prevented the PDF in this case, there would be no guarantee the links were correct. The easiest way to tell that just is to look at the terminal output. (Or log. Or your editor's summary of the log.)

IMHO this is a XY problem: How to avoid to use PDFs, which are generated from code with mistakes? And this is more or less a production system issue not a real LaTeX issue. LaTeX already provides information about several kinds of mistakes. You “just” have to use them before trusting the generated PDFs.

@cabohah - Ok. Thanks.
